# How to delete the first child of an element but referenced by $(this) in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The scenario is I have two `div`s: one is where I select items (`divResults`) and it goes to the next div (`divSelectedContacts`). When I select it I place a tick mark next to it. What I want to do is when I select it again I want to remove the tick mark and also remove the element from `divSelectedContacts`.

Here is the code:

```
$("#divResults li").click(function()
{
    if ($(this).find('span').size() == 1)
    {
        var copyElement = $(this).children().clone();
        $(this).children().prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check checked' style='float:left'></span>");
        $("#divSelectedContacts").append(copyElement);
    } else
    {
        var deleteElement = $(this).find('span'); //here is the problem how to find the first span and delete it
        $(deleteElement).remove();
        var copyElement = $(this).children().clone();//get the child element
        $("#divSelectedContacts").find(copyElement).remove(); //remove that element by finding it
    }
});
```

I don't know how to select the first `span` in a `li` using `$(this)`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Several ways:

```
$(this).find('span:first');

$(this).find(':first-child');

$(this).find('span').eq(0);
```

Note that you don't need to use `$(deleteElement)` as `deleteElement` is already a jQuery object. So you can do it like this:

```
$(this).find('span:first').remove();
```

Comment: Thank you so much :-). The deleteElement didn't occur to me. Good catch.

Answer (score 6):

To get the *first child* of `$(this)` use this:

```
$(this).find(":first-child");
```

Answer (score 5):

or you could just throw it all into the selector...

```
$('span:first', this);
```

Comment: sweet I like this implementation. +1 for you.